# Is there a numpy function to convert from log(e) to log(10)?

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a single numpy function convert log(e) numbers to log(10) numbers? If so, would the single function be faster than this code?

```
y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
np.log10(np.exp(y))
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not think there is a `numpy` function (and I hope to be corrected), but the standard mathematical way is faster than what you have shown.

That is, you would simply divide `log_e(n)` by the constant `log_e(10)` to obtain `log_10(n)`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. It is called division. :-)

Just divide by `log(10)`.

For details, see http://www.sosmath.com/algebra/logs/log4/log43/log43.html

That said, Numpy already has both [`log()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log.html) and [`log10()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log10.html), so it's not entirely clear why you even need to perform the conversion.

Answer (score 2):

The function is the division function:

```
z = y / np.log(10)
```